# How to Read Name of array in from JObject in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

This is the array that i am getting from an api response and I want to read "591460000000352107" this value. This is the key of array and that will be different in every response of api. so how can I read it from `JObject` in C#:

```
{"response": { "result": [{"591460000000352107": [{"Middle_Name": "","EmailID":"prateek.chauhan@gmail.com","Expertise": ""}]}]}}
```

Comment: Your array consist of a single element, which is an object which in turn just has one property. I suggest you draw out the structure of the response in terms of JObject, JArray etc - then it'll be easy to work out how to access it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var jobj = JObject.Parse(json);
foreach (var result in (jobj["response"]["result"]))
    foreach (var key in (result as JObject).Properties())
        Console.WriteLine(key.Name);
```

You can iterate over the results and get the name of the keys